# DROP TABLE with uninstall hook not working

Tags: plugins, wp-query, database, table

I wanted to explore more options and thats the reason for me building my first WP Plugin. I tryed to follow the coding standards, but I am struggeling hard right now. I am trying to drop my created database tables, when the uninstall hook is triggered. I am trying for 6 Hours now, using google, youtube, stackoverflow and more, but not getting any working result for me.

When I activate my plugin, I create 2 tables in my database. I want to delete these two tables, while uninstall this plugin.

My code:

```
// create uninstall hook

register_uninstall_hook( __FILE__ , 'uninstall_function' );

function uninstall_function() {
    global $wpdb;

    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "one_of_two_tables";

    $sql_delete = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $table_name";

    $wpdb->query( $sql_delete );
}
```

I also tryed this (found on stackoverflow):

```
function delete_plugin_database_tables(){
    global $wpdb;
    $tableArray = [   
      $wpdb->prefix . "table_name1",
      $wpdb->prefix . "table_name2",
   ];

  foreach ($tableArray as $tablename) {
     $wpdb->query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $tablename");
  }
}
```

This code is inside of the plugin main file, not in the uninstall.php and it is wrapped by the activation function (hook). I dont know anymore.. any help :D?

**Update!** So just to let you know: Its working with an uninstall.php. Not the way I wanted to do it, but its working for now. If someone does know why my uninstall hook is not working, just let me know. Otherwise I use the uninstall.php for now on.

Comment: Where is this being added `register_uninstall_hook()`? If it's a separate file, are you sure you're including that file into your main plugin?

Comment: Can you not use `uninstall.php`? If the plugin is not active then there's no way to register the uninstall hook. Is it that the table isn't deleted, or that the hook does not run?

Comment: Hey @Howdy_McGee -> no its the main file. So i just have one php file right now.

Comment: Hey @Tom J Nowell -> Why should I use an other file, for  just deleting 2 tables?

Comment: Can you answer my other question, I asked wether the problem is that the uninstall hook does not run, or that it does run but the table is not dropped.

Comment: I have followed this guys videos for themes and plugins which has helped a lot! Try seeing if this helps you :) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FpnHvp9x48c&list=PLriKzYyLb28kR_CPMz8uierDWC2y3znI2&index=6

Comment: @tom-j-nowell how should I know? I mean inside of the hook is just the delete tables function. Any tipps?

Comment: Create a file called `uninstall.php` and place your **Delete tables** code inside that. DO NOT place it inside a function, just place it as raw code.